# LINQ All and Any complex object

Tags: vb.net, linq

I got the following code and I always get the same error, but I am not able to find out why as in the first level (All function) I can use can compare the complex object but within the Any function it gives me the followin error.

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'ConsoleApplication1.Param'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context

This is the code

```
  Dim listParams As List(Of Param) = Nothing

  listParams = New List(Of Param)(2)

  Dim new_param as Param

  new_param = new Param()
  new_param.Name = "p1"
  new_param.Value = "a"
  listParams.Add(new_param)

  new_param = new Param()
  new_param.Name = "p2"
  new_param.Value = "231"
  listParams.Add(new_param)

  Dim aux As IQueryable(Of Part)

  aux = From p In CurrentBD.Parts
        Where p.code = find_pattern _
          And p.version = find_version _
          And p.Params.Count = listParams.Count _
          And p.Params.All(Function(p1 As Parametro) listParams.Any(Function(p2) p2.Name = p1.Name AndAlso (p2.Value = p1.Value OrElse p1.Value = "IRRELEVANT")) )
        Select p

  Dim hist_part as Part
  hist_part = aux.FirstOrDefault()
```

The point of the query is to get all registered parts that belongs to pattern but, where the value and name of the parameters of the part, all match to the once in the list

Am I doing something wrong? Obviously I am, What???

Thanks in advance, to anyone that can help me or give me a clue.

Comment: What does your class definition for `Param` look like? You cannot use complex objects (anything that is more than simple fields/properties) within queries like that. If you have other methods and whatnot in that class, you will not be able to use it.

Comment: This is the definition of the class





  Public Class Param
    Public Name As String
    Public Value As String
  End Class

Comment: Why are you nesting the .All with the .Any?

Comment: On which line does the error happen?

Comment: Hello Rob: 
I want to find a part where all this parameter fetch parameters I got in a list. The point is that the parameters in the list are calculated, and the point is to find if that part has been already created or not

Comment: Hi Neolisk:
I got the error on 
`hist_part = aux.FirstOrDefault()` 
line, but if I remove the 
`And p.Params.All(Function(p1 As Parametro) listParams.Any(Function(p2) p2.Name = p1.Name AndAlso (p2.Value = p1.Value OrElse p1.Value = "IRRELEVANT")) )` line of the select statement I got no error

Even if I replace it with something like this

`And p.Params.All(Function(p1 As Parametro) p2.Name = "XXXX" AndAlso (p2.Value = "50" OrElse p1.Value = "IRRELEVANT")) )`


, with no Any statements, it works, but it does not mixing all and any

Comment: @xbikuna What is the class definition of Parametro? 'Cause if I'm not mistaking you're trying to make a Parametro out of a Part?

Comment: From the error it sounds to me like you have something in there which cannot be compared in SQL, as in a complex type. I would load the minimum number of objects into memory first and execute the second part of the query using linq to objects rather than linq to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Error here:

```
p.Params.All(Function(p1 As Parametro) listParams.Any(Function(p2) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this clause of the query:

```
p.Params.All(Function(p1 As Parametro) listParams.Any(Function(p2) ...
```

The variable `listParams` is a local list, so the `Any` call needs to be evaluated locally (not on the SQL server). However, it's contained within a lambda expression which needs to be evaluated on the SQL side (`p.Params.All()`), which is not possible. The only local-list (IEnumerable rather than IQueryable) operation which Entity Framework supports is `Contains`, which is translated into an `IN` statement on the SQL side. You could try refactoring your `Any` to use `Contains` instead, although that might be difficult. I would probably split it up into a clause which filtered down to name, then do the value filtering on the client side:

```
// create listParamNames list containing only names, then update query
//...
p.Params.All(Function(p1 As Parametro) listParamNames.Contains(p1.Name))
//...
```